# iOS: Object returns nil description after alloc and init

Tags: ios, objective-c

Object returns nil description after alloc and init..can any one tell me i have to display the data which comes from server...when i clicks on edit button it goes to shoow room class in that class.. inside textfields hav to display the information .can any one help me

```
@interface HeadOfficeDetails : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *ofcContact;

@property(nonatomic,strong) OfficeDocument *ofcDocument;
@property(nonatomic,strong) OfficePrice *ofcPrice;
@property(nonatomic,strong) CityClass *city;
@property(nonatomic,strong) StateClass *state;
@property(nonatomic,strong) DistrictClass *district;

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *shrtname;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *shwrmname;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *shop;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *door;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *buildng;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *flr;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *tele;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *pin;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *main;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *dist;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *designan;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *depart;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *emai;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *mobile;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *strt;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *area;


@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *jwleryname;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *officeid;


-(void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes;




///////////////////////////////////////////////
showroom class



 headdetails=[[HeadOfficeDetails alloc]init];


self.txtshowroom.text=headdetails.jwleryname;
NSLog(@"%@ :",self.txtshowroom.text);


NSNumber *officeid=headdetails.officeid;
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",officeid]);

[self.txtshortname setText:headdetails.jwleryname];
[self.txtshowroom setText:headdetails.shwrmname];
[self.txtstreet setText:headdetails.strt];
[self.txtarea setText:headdetails.area];
[self.txtmain setText:headdetails.main];
[self.txtbuilding setText:headdetails.buildng];
[self.txtname setText:self.cntctcls.contactname];
[self.txtdesign setText:self.cntctcls.desig];
[self.txtdepartmnt setText:self.cntctcls.depart];
[self.txtmbl setText:self.cntctcls.mobile];
[self.txtemail setText:self.cntctcls.email];
[self.txtfloor setText:headdetails.flr];
[self.txttel setText:headdetails.tele];
[self.txtpincode setText:headdetails.pin];
[self.txtshop setText:headdetails.shop];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are i put example code for show `NSObject` class data that save during data fetch from server and show on another class by using its instance.

Following is create a NSObject class for storing FBLogin userDetauls:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FBUser : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *FBUserId;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *FBUserName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *FBUserFirstName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *FBUserLasttName;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *FBUserEmail;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *FBUserBio;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *FBUserLocation;

+(instancetype)SharedFBUser;
-(void)ClearFBuser;
+(NSString*)CheckEmtryElseAlert:(NSString*)strValue;

@end
```

Following is an Implementation class here we create `SharedFBUser` that allcate `FBUser` object once if that found nil so when no need to do code `alloc` `init` during show time

```
#import "FBUser.h"


static FBUser* fbObject;

@implementation FBUser

+(instancetype)SharedFBUser
{
    if(fbObject == nil)
    {
        fbObject =[[FBUser alloc]init];
    }

    return fbObject;
}
-(void)ClearFBuser
{

    fbObject = nil;
    self.FBUserId = nil;
    self.FBUserName = nil;
    self.FBUserFirstName =nil;
    self.FBUserLasttName = nil;
    self.FBUserEmail = nil;
    self.FBUserBio = nil;
    self.FBUserLocation = nil;

}
```

Now following code for how to use `FBUser` class for save data .H class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FBUser.h"
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic,strong)FBUser *fbObject;
@end
```

And you can save data in FBCallback:

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSLog(@"resultis:%@",result);
             [FBUser SharedFBUser].FBUserId =[result valueForKey:@"id"];
             [FBUser SharedFBUser].FBUserEmail =[result valueForKey:@"email"];
              [FBUser SharedFBUser].FBUserName =[result valueForKey:@"name"];
             [FBUser SharedFBUser].FBUserFirstName =[result valueForKey:@"first_name"];
             [FBUser SharedFBUser].FBUserLasttName =[result valueForKey:@"last_name"];
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
         }
     }];
```

And following code for show the data that have stored in `FBuser` class

```
 #import "FBUser.h"
    self.lblEmail.text = [FBUser SharedFBUser].FBUserEmail;
    self.lblusename.text = [FBUser SharedFBUser].FBUserName;
    self.lblfirstname.text = [FBUser SharedFBUser].FBUserFirstName;
    self.lbllastname.text = [FBUser SharedFBUser].FBUserLasttName;
```

Hope that help this fully description about use and create. this is my working code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you doing, may you need something like parse dictionary to object first.

`headdetails=[[HeadOfficeDetails alloc]init];`

New Object created so all properties will nil.

you need assign value for it like

```
headdetails=[[HeadOfficeDetails alloc]initWithDictionary:attributes];
```

You can parse it your self or looking some 3rd library like:[JSonModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel)

Comment: i would like to show the data in text fields when ever the user clicks on edit button and once i update any thing in text field it wil update

Comment: i have nsobject class there i have set the key values

Comment: When you request data from server, you will get JSON return back, you first need parse it to your custom object and after that you can map it to your UI. I thing you are new to iOS development, let read some of book for beginner first. RayWenderlic had alot of good tutorial, you can read this one https://www.raywenderlich.com/55384/ios-7-best-practices-part-1 to understanding your problem face with.